# View record from specific / custom date range

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help
I'm creating a web database (PHP) with database like this post

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94545/calculate-row-value-based-on-previous-and-actual-row-values

I follow his instruction and get same result like this

[image: Result]

my question is, how if I want to show some data using search record between specific or custom dates (example from 17-06-2014 to 14-08-2014),

[image: Example result]

as you can see, my result show the balance field was filled with wrong values, it shows first row balance as 20000, I was expecting first balance should be 23000 (3000 from last record + 20000 from current transaction)

how to do that?

Comment: Can you add some code you tried because now you only show a query. Also look at [ask] a question

Comment: to @Broebie  : I dont use any code, just creating a table like that in mysql database, fill it with values like the example, generate some PHP page so I can access it using my web browser. I add that query, and it works as  expected, then when I want to view some data/record with specific condition (like from this date to that date) using "advanced search" button, the 'balance' field was showing wrong values like that. the calculation was restarted from 0, not cumulative from previous value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the WHERE clause for you date ranges, like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
    s.stmnt_date, s.debit, s.credit,
    @b := @b + s.debit - s.credit AS balance
FROM
    (SELECT @b := 0.0) AS dummy 
  CROSS JOIN
    statements AS s
ORDER BY
    stmnt_date
    ) AS Temp
WHERE Temp.stmnt_date >='2014-06-17' AND Temp.stmnt_date <='2014-08-14'
```

Comment: that may work, but if I want to view other date range record i think i must create new query right? can you tell me how's the efficient way if i want to view some data/record with specific condition (like from this date to that date)

Comment: @Gnometa I don't understand what/where is your "advanced search button"?

Comment: I'm  sorry, i just edited the answer for your comment. 

that comment is for @BRoebie in his comment below my question, i was writing on wrong field.